# Como pegar o mês seguinte e o ano em ASP clássico?

Tags: visual-basic-6, asp

Por exemplo: estamos em março de 2015. Eu consigo pegar o mês seguinte do ano corrente usando `month()+1` concatenando com `year()`, ou seja, o mês de abril de 2015. Porém, digamos que estivéssemos em dezembro de 2015, como eu pego automaticamente o mês de janeiro **e o ano de 2016**? Existe alguma função que faça isso sem eu ter que fazer comparação do mês?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode adicionar ou remover internvalos de tempo a uma data com a função [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262710%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), 3 é preciso informar 3 argumentos: o intervalo, quantidade e a data.

Intervalos disponíveis

```
yyyy |  Ano
q    |  Quarto
m    |  Mês
y    |  Dia do ano
d    |  Dia
w    |  Dia da semana
ww   |  Semana
h    |  Hora
n    |  Minuto
s    |  Segundo
```

Exemplo:

```
<% 
  data = "2015-01-01"
  response.write month(DateAdd("m", -1, data)) &" - "& year(DateAdd("m", -1, data))
  response.write month(DateAdd("m", 12, data)) &" - "& year(DateAdd("m", 12, data))
%>
```

Saída:

```
12 - 2014
1 -  2016
```